# RISCV RV32IM: MULHSU - which operand is the signed one?

Tags: riscv

#### Question

In the risc-v RV32IM, for instruction `MULHSU`, which one of operands `rs1` and `rs2` is the signed operand?

#### Background

The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual
Volume I: Unprivileged ISA
Document Version 20190608-Base-Ratified
say the following (near bottom page 43):

> MULH, MULHU, and MULHSU perform the same multiplication but return the upper XLEN bits of the full 2 × XLEN-bit product, for signed × signed, unsigned × unsigned, and signed rs1 × unsigned rs2 multiplication, respectively.

So this states that the signed operand is `rs1`. 
But the explicatory note (bottom page 43) say:

> MULHSU  is  used  in  multi-word  signed  multiplication  to  multiply  the  most-significant  word  of the  multiplier  (which  contains  the  sign  bit)  with  the  less-significant  words  of  the  multiplicand (which are unsigned).

From the definition of the instruction (also page 43):

```
 31    25 24      20 19         15 14          12 11  7 6      0
+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+-----+--------+
| funct7 | rs2      | rs1         | funct3       | rd  | opcode |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+-----+--------+
  7        5          5             3              5     7
  MULDIV   multiplier multiplicand  MUL/MUL[[S]U]  dest  OP
```

I see that the multiplier is rs2. So the explicatory note states that the signed operand is `rs2`.

Comment: have you tried it on an sifive product to see what their implementation is and/or look at the foundation source code to see their implementation.  from what you posted it does appear like a documentation bug, another approach would be to just ask the risc-v foundation folks, I assume there is a forum

Comment: I think you've just found a documentation issue. You should report it on the [official github](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual) instead. There's the [clarify which operand is signed vs unsigned for mulhsu](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues/270) issue to fix the main text but probably they forgot to fix the footer

Comment: @phuclv, I think you are right. I've followed your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe either the diagram or "explicatory note" has a typo. All of my testing has shown **rs1 to be signed and rs2 to be unsigned for MULHSU.**

A much more comprehensive summary of instruction formats & pseudo-codes can be found [here](https://rv8.io/isa.html).  More detail of pseudo-instructions and other things to help write assembly code for RISC-V can be found [here](https://rv8.io/asm.html) (same website).  Its documentation specifically expresses MULHSU as follows :

```
MULHSU rd, rs1, rs2     #rd ← (sx(rs1) × ux(rs2)) » xlen
```

where sx(r) means signed version, and ux(r) means unsigned version.

If you find any evidence that this isn't the case, please let me know.

Comment: I kick myself, I knew about http://rv8.io/asm.htm. This is what is stated in the main text of $7.1. I've opened an issue to get the note in $7.1 updated, see https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues/463.

Answer (score 0):

Following communication with riscv fundation: **`rs1` is the signed operand**.
See https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues/463